# Using worksheet variable instead of explicit sheet name ,throw “Compile error: Method or data member not found”

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am basically need to list  a `sheet ComboBox` when I open the workbook.
If I used a variable instead of sheet name ,I got this error:

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate
 
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
 
    sh.ComboBox1.List = sh.Range("D3:D10").Value    'this cause Compile error
 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).ComboBox1.List = sh.Range("D3:D10").Value  'this works correctly
 
End Sub
```

So, How to use a variable `sh` instead of explicitly sheet name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either declare it as `Object` - since the Worksheet class does not have a `Combobox1` property, or using the sheet codename - e.g. `Dim sh as Sheet2`.

```
Dim sh As Object
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
sh.ComboBox1.List = sh.Range("D3:D10").Value
```

or:

```
Dim sh As Sheet2
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
sh.ComboBox1.List = sh.Range("D3:D10").Value
```

Alternatively, keep it as a `Worksheet` variable and use its `OLEObjects` property to refer to the control by name:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

sh.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.List = sh.Range("D3:D10").Value
```

Comment: Could you share an example of what you meant before *Alternatively...*?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sure - amended above.

Comment: Both options works perfectly. It is new for me to know that a variable can be declared by the sheet codename itself.